# Limit calculation help

Tags: limits

> $$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}$$

For some reason, I am stuck calculating this limit. Can't seem to find it directly or get anything from L'Hopital's rule. Please help.

Comment: What is the limit tending towards? Also it'd be better if you included your scratch work so we can better guide you towards the correct answer.

Comment: Presumably, thats $f(n) = \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}$ (right click on this and you can get the tex code for it). What limit are you concerned with? $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$?

Comment: Yes, limit as n goes to infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing typo's, I rewrite the function $$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}$$ and we shall look at what is going when $x$ becomes very large. Instinctivley, you could say that for a very large value of $x$, $x+1$ does not differ from $x$, so, basically your function behaves as $$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x}{x}}=1$$ A more rigorous way would consist in writing $x+1=x(1+\frac{1}{x})$ and then, without altering anything $$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}=\sqrt{\frac{x}{x \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{ 1+\frac{1}{x}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}}$$ and arrive to same conclusions. If you are more requiring, you can use the fact that, for marginal values of $y$, $(1+y)^n$ is almost $(1+ny)$. Then replace $y$ by $1/x$ and $n$ by $-1/2$ to arrive to $(1-\frac{1}{2 x})$ which, by the way, is the start of the Taylor series, since for large values of $x$ the function is approximated by $$
1-\frac{1}{2 x}+\frac{3}{8 x^2}-\frac{5}{16 x^3}+\frac{35}{128
   x^4}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^5\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $n/(n+1)=1-1/(n+1)$, by induction we can show that $(1-1/(n+1))^K\rightarrow1$ for $K\in \mathbb{N}$ (why?). Let $K\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $K>1/2$. Then:

$$(1-1/{(n+1)})^{K}\le(1-1/{(n+1)})^{1/2}\le1$$

Thus by the squeeze theorem we have $(1-1/{(n+1)})^{1/2} \rightarrow 1$.